# How to pipe input to SLURM's sbatch?

Tags: linux, slurm, hpc

I have a job script called `testjob.sh` which I submit as

```
sbatch testjob.sh
```

Is it possible to pipe some input to the script? If I ran as a simple command, I would do

```
echo 1 2 3 4 | ./testjob.sh
```

however, with SLURM, I tried the following and it does not work:

```
echo 1 2 3 4 | sbatch testjob.sh
```

My example script is this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --export=ALL
#SBATCH --job-name=jobname
#SBATCH -e jobname.err
#SBATCH -o jobname.out
#SBATCH -p RM-shared
#SBATCH -n 1
#SBATCH --time=00:05:00

echo "jobscipt"
while read -r input 
do
        echo "from jobscipt $input"
done
```

and the outputs:

```
#this one worked
> echo 1 2 3 4 | ./testjob.sh
jobscipt
from jobscipt 1 2 3 4

#slurm did not take the input
> echo 1 2 3 4 | sbatch testjob.sh
Submitted batch job 3758713
> cat jobname.out
jobscipt
```

I know it's possible to set arguments to `sbatch` via setting environmental variables with `--export`, but how would I pipe an input to it? A workaround to pipe would be a temporary file but that's not particularly elegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sbatch` runs the job in a different environment ("in the background"), therefore you can't pipe stuff into the scripts.

You can avoid this in two ways:

- use `srun` instead of `sbatch`, which doesn't disconnect the job from your session and piping works more-or-less normally. Still, this doesn't allow you to "queue" the job as with batches.
- use intermediate file for saving the input, i.e., modify the batch file to read the input from `testjob.in`:

```sh
while read -r input
do
   ...
done < testjob.in
```

and put your input into the intermediate file before enqueueing the batch:

```sh
echo 1 2 3 4 > testjob.in
sbatch testjob.sh
```